# How long does one need to work and pay taxes, to qualify for Social Security retirement ( USA)

Tags: social-security

I have looked on SS sites and other sites and saw no answer. Long ago I think "40 quarters" ( 10 years) of paying social security taxes were required before one could collect SS retirement if you were old enough. It looks to me that one could pay SS taxes a couple months and then retire with SS benefits if age 67+ ; although benefits would be very low. I am not asking for myself as I paid in the max for 40 years.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.ssa.gov/planners/credits.html?  If yes, can you explain which part is not clear?

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "bureaucrat speech" that a quarter is now called a "credit". And I was remembering the early 60's when some people were eligible for lifetime SS retirement payments by making a 2 year lump-sum payment to SS .